# installing passenger on Apache2 using rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, passenger, rvm

I've installed Apache2 and it runs okay.

And I've installed **rvm** following [this link](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you).

After that, I've execute follow commands as its order. Actually some of these commands are from [this link](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) installing **redmine**.

```
rvm install 1.8.7
rvm use 1.8.7
gem install rails -v=2.3.5
gem install postgres-pr pq
gem install i18n -v=0.4.2

gem install passenger
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

and append this to apache2.conf

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/myhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/myhome/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330/gems/passenger-3.0.2
PassengerRuby /home/myhome/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p330/ruby
```

This is log for Apache after restart

```
[notice] Apache/2.2.16 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3 with Suhosin-Patch Phusion_Passenger/3.0.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

But!!!, if I open my redmine root page, it just shows file list in public directory. I think Passenger may not work correctly.

Why? and how to fix this? I've tried everything what I can do for 2 days T-T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added this section to apache config? It tells apache that you are using Rails application:

```
<VirtualHost :*80>
  ServerName myapp
  DocumentRoot /root-to-your-path/public
</VirtualHost>
```

And restarted Apache? Read more here: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_ruby_on_rails_application

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer was worth as my 2 days!

Answer (score 1):

You should view the [Passenger Integration guide](http://rvm.io/integration/passenger) from RVM, or the more detailed [guide from Phusion](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/) (the makers of Passenger).

Note that in Phusion's guide, you should omit the `--pre` when installing the gem, as the guide was written when Passenger 3 was still in beta.

Comment: installed passenger using 'gem install passenger --pre' and launched 'passenger-install-apache2-module' again, but same problem...T-T